# UILongPressGestureRecognizer pass touches to UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I added `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to `UIWebView`:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTouch:)];
longPress.delegate = self;
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
longPress.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;

[_webView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

`cancelsTouchesInView` set to `YES`, but after long press on *hyperlink* touch pass to `UIWebView` and `UIWebView` click on this *hyperlink* and load other page.

How can I disable touches to `UIWebView` after long press?

Answer (score 0):

You may used below code to prevent touch links inside of webview content -

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL allowLoad;

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return allowLoad;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
    allowLoad = NO;
}
```

Don't forgot to set delegate  `[self.webView setDelegate:self];`

Hope this will be help you

Comment: This code prohibits all clicks on hyperlinks. But I do not need to ban them. I need to disable pass touches to UIWebView only if long press.

Answer (score 0):

Implement below gesture delegate method to prevent web view touch on long press:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.webView])
    {
        //Ignore gesture when it's web view
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Update**

Please try with below code -

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];   
}
```

Comment: This code is not working. After long press still is clicked on the hyperlink in UIWebView.

Comment: This javascript code I is already present in my project, but it does not solve the problem that I have described.